# Testing: The best way to add test data in DB

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, testing, testng

Sorry for my English. Are there any tools for adding / generating test data into the database? I would like to know who and how to add test data in the database and what tools are used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what test artifacts management system you are using, what APIs it exposes, and then write your own code to interact with the API.